# Android: 1 Adapter to multiple Array Lists

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a base adapter and 5 array lists which contain different data. 
Based on a selection, the contents of the array list are populated on the list view.
At the current moment this functions correctly, however each time, a new selection is made, an entire new adapter is being made and set. Would like to know if there is an alternative way of changing the data displayed without having to set a new adapter.,

I am fully aware of notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: You can combine the arraylists objects into a single object, and then use single arraylist. Then you can use notify.

Comment: if you are changing the arraylist amongst the 5 then setting the new adapter is the way to go

Comment: @IllegalArgument Yes the problem with that is according to this link http://dendirken.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/dont-loose-your-position-in-an-android-listview/ causes a problem when attempting to preserve list view scroll position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an ArrayAdapter (just a guess), then there are functions to change the used list (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

```
clear()
addAll(Collection<t> c)
```